# Python datetime formatting for yyyy-mm

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

Im have a csv file with date data which is formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'yyyy-mm'.

When i import the csv file and convert to a dataframe, the datatype of my date column is object.
Im trying to convert this to datetime, but whenever i do, the dates which are formatted 'yyyy-mm' get converted to format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

How can i convert the data from object to date but preserve the 'yyyy-mm' format?
Ive tried the methods 'pd.to_datetime', 'strptime' and 'strftime' which all result in my data changing to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't. If you parse to datetime data type, there is no "format" - yyyy-mm-dd is just how this data type is displayed to you. If you want to have output in a certain format, it has to be of data type string and you get there by calling `strftime` with a certain [formatting directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: Dates will always have a year, month *and* day. If you want just years and months (and sometimes days), you may consider using three separate columns instead. But since you're not stating *why* you want the output to be "yyyy-mm", that may not be useful.

Comment: thanks, thats good to know it is not possible! i was hoping to use the PandasSchema package to validate date formats, which requires a datetime. Thanks for your help

Comment: Validating the *formats* should effectively only require the input string. Then try to convert that, and see if it goes through. E.g., `pd.to_datetime(['2011-11-11', '2014-10', '2016-05-06', '2020-12'])` will work fine, setting the day to the first of the month when there is no day given; which then tells you that all those four dates are correct. Add '2018-18' somewhere in that list, and you get a (lengthy) error message stating that there is a "bad month number 18; must be 1-12".